# Print text dynamically in a printer using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, api, printing

Please tell me the class to be used to print a paragraph of text that is to be printed on a printer, In vb.net, more than 1 page of text must be dynamically printed by retrieving data from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) class.  The MSDN article I linked has a fairly simple example, but for something a little more elaborate there's [this tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/44150-printing-in-vbnet/).  In the tutorial the author extends `PrintDocument` to wrap a lot of the property settings you'd need to make to allow for simpler printing calls but still maintain a lot of the control the class has to offer.